# Does jQuery off method remove event listeners added with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am working on an old code and I have seen in the code that there are many events added with javascript addEventListener and some added with jQuery.on() on the same element but in the detach method it is used only jQuery.off() to remove them. So I was wondering if this code will work as the guys that wrote it expected (to remove all events from the dom element) or the events added with javascript won't be removed.

Comment: Go through http://api.jquery.com/off/ its clearly mentioned _The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`._

Comment: You could try it yourself... https://jsfiddle.net/a4snnpw3/

Comment: So it won't remove any other events, no matter if added with addEventListener, jQuery bind and so on ?

Comment: `bind()` has been deprecated so shouldn't be used regardless, but `off()` would remove those too. It removes any event handler added via jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/a4snnpw3/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested it myself but wasn't sure cuz I am still new to javascript and jQuery so I wanted to hear the thoughts of more experienced people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.

If you investigate the native `removeEventListener` api you can see that it expects the original callback for a successful removal.  As far as I'm aware, there is no native way for removing all event listeners on a node.

jQuery acts as an intermediary for much of what it does.  It does this so that it can maintain control of its api with things like `on` and `off`.

This won't be an issue if you write your code in such a way that it tracks adds so that you can later do some kind of cleanup step; however, it does put the onus on you.

Now if all browsers supported `getEventListeners` as Chrome does this could be a different story.  Read [this](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/412) for an understanding of why this is not desirable.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because Satpal only commented on my question, but he was the first that answered it, so I wanted to give him some credit. Nonetheless, thanks for the time and even if it was too late for me when you added your answer I hope that someone else who is having the same question will gain from your answer and from seeing that this question has been answered.