# jQuery what could cause .off() to be ignored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Let's assume there is this form on a website:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart">
<!--Some inputs here-->
<button type="submit" name="checkout">Checkout</button>
</form>
```

And this javascript code I use to change form button behavior:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("*").off()
  $(document).on('click',"*",function(e){  
      alert(1)
      e.preventDefault(); 
  });
  jQuery('*').unbind().submit(function(e) {       
      return false;
  })
}, 1);
```

This is just as example, I know I should not use interval and * selector. Since selector * is used (just for testing), I can exclude the selector is not correct. By using interval (just for testing) I can exclude option that bind is used later.

Theoretically without real example, what could cause that off and click event are still ignored?

Comment: What do you expect the code to do and what does actually happen?

Comment: I expect the code to remove all events attached to this form button and trigger alert(1). But it doesn't, it still processes the form in old way and ingores my code.

Comment: @JohnClark are you sure, I tried it and it exploded with a bajillion alerts when I tried it. Probably because there is one attached every time the `setInterval` callback is invoked which, in turn, would be multiple times per second. I'm not sure why you use an interval, though.

Comment: Yes of course it works if you try it alone, what I am trying to find out is why it doesn't work if I put this code in console when I am on the website which has many javascript files included. I can not give url, this is why I am asking what could theoretically prevent this code to not work. I thought $("*").off() would remove all events and won't allow form to be submitted. But I am wrong. Are in javascript there other things beside events that could make some action on button click/submit?

Comment: I think I found answer. I assumed I can remove events created with addEventListener with jQuery, apparently you can not. jQuery can only unbind all event handlers for a given event if the original listeners were configured using jQuery. I guess I need to use native js function removeEventListener and I won't be able to unbind events with jquery.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715451/does-jquery-off-method-remove-event-listeners-added-with-addeventlistener)